# Can the Predictors be Count Variable for Logistic Regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, poisson-regression

I have a general question regarding logistic regression. May I know if the predictors of logistic regression (mixed effect with random variables) could be count variables (e.g., 6,10,20,21)? I understand that for logistic regression the outcome variable needs to be binary. However, my experiment explores the relationship between the number of times readers read a word to the chance of acquiring it (1 for learned, 0 for unlearned). May I know if I could still use logistic regression in such a case? If I can not, may I know what mixed-effect regression model I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as the assumptions of the logistic regression are met, you can do that[(A simple guide to checking assumptions in R)](https://rpubs.com/guptadeepak/logit-assumptions).
However, always check for [Zero-inflated model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model), and if that is the case, you should define meaningful cut-offs in this variable to turn it into a categorical predictor (Such as more than zero and zero, etc)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions  and sharing the links to the learning materials. Yes, my dependent variable contains lots of zeros. So, I will check for Zero-inflated model to see if it could fit my data. Thanks.